# Generic class with unused generic parameter in constructor

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

I want to do following:

```
public class My<T>
{
   public My(G<S> g, T t)
   {
       // code that DOES NOT use S in any way
   } 
}
```

I'm getting 'Cannot resolve symbol S'.
Is it possible to do it somehow? And if not, why? 
I can't change G, it's not my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike member function, constructors cannot specify generic types in their declaration. To work around this you'll need to lift the generic type out of the constructor and into the class declaration:

```
public class My<T,S>
{
   public My(G<S> g, T t)
   {
       // code that DOES NOT use S in any way
   } 
}
```

This may be a problem if you intend to have various constructors that take additional generic types.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either:

1. Remove the need for the `<S>` or `G<S>` (ie. replace it with a non-generic type, an interface, etc.)
2. or Add `S` as a generic parameter to the type:

   ```
   public class My<T, S>
   {
      public My(G<S> g, T t)
      {
          // code that DOES NOT use S in any way
      } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. 
I don't need S. But type G is not covariant, so I cannot accept smth like G<object>.

Do you know if there is any philosophical reason why solving this is not possible or is it just a tech limitation of C#?

Comment: The compiler needs to know what `S` will be. The code will be different if `S` is a value type compared to a reference type, and even different for different value types.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare S explicitly in your method :

```
public class My<T, S>
{
   public My(G<S> g, T t)
   {
       // code that DOES NOT use S in any way
   } 
}
```

This will compile (except if you have some conditions on S on G class). You will have to declare what is S in any case when using the My class.

Example will G< S > = Nullable< S > :

```
public class My<T, S> where S : struct
{
    public My(Nullable<S> g, T t)
    {
        // code that DOES NOT use S in any way
    }
}
```

With this implementation, you have to define S when using the My class (in that case S is int):

```
var myVar = new My<string, int>(4, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Does not seem to work with constructor.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

User following implementation:

```
public class My<T, S>
{
  public My(G<S> g, T t)
  {
    // Now S will be accessible.
  }
}
```